# Sheet deactive to hide the columns i want

Tags: vba, excel

How do I hide columns of the sheet when I move away from the sheet?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Deactivate()
    Columns("A:K").Select
    Selection.EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    Sheets("MASTER").Select
End Sub
```

The sheet I want the columns to be hidden in is sheet `reference`.

Comment: What happens when your code runs? Doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are deactivating worksheet, the default worksheet becomes the active worksheet that you swithced to, so when using ranges without sheet reference, i.e. `Columns("A:K")`, they refer to columns in **current** worksheet. That's why you should always use references to worksheets, i.e.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Worksheets("reference")
```

And then use it to reference ranges in it:

```
ws.Columns("A:K").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
```

Not that I got rid out of the `Select` method, which is very discouraged to use.

This might be really helpful for you: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Answer (score 0):

Columns("A:K").EntireColumn.Hidden = True